# Make Store Homepage in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to find out how I can make the store page on my woocommerce site as the homepage. I currently have WordPress 4.7.2 installed using the eStore Theme 1.1.5 and I am trying to replicate the template from the following link:

https://wordpress.org/themes/estore/

My current site on my localhost (attached) [image: mysite] has a button for the shop page but i would like to make this my homepage and then have the banners as displayed on the above link (kids clothes, shoe collection) but I am not sure how I go about changing this so would really appreciate some advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
METHOD 1:

 Add [products] shortcode to your existing home page, update it and its done.

METHOD 2:

    Follow these steps:

    Step 1: create a New Page, Give it a suitable Title.

    Step 2: Make sure that the permalink of this page must be like: http://www.example.com/shop/

    Step 3: Now go to Settings->Reading Select the above created Page as the Front page. save settings.

    Step 4: visit your website.
```